# how to align the left most border and right most border of all tables in word 07?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word 07 doc with many tables interposed with texts through the whole doc, what i do is only to mouse click and drag one by one, and sometimes you can't see the previous table if they are far apart. How do i align the left most borders and right most borders of all of them?